# batch for speed test [Share drive]

Tags: performance, batch-file, testing, powerpoint

I'm new to write batch file. I want to write a batch file, such that I can test out the speed for fully opening a large power point file from network share drive.The powerpoint file is stored at server, and usually will take minutes to fully open up due to slow network line and heavy graphic oriented.

But I have no idea how to identify if the powerpoint file is completely opened after the start command is run. Anyone can help? Thank you.

Below is some of my code.

```
@echo off
set logfile=C:\logs\powerpoint.log
set destination=C:\logs

:loop
echo Open Powerpoint file test STARTING at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
start S:\Presentation1.ppt
echo Open Powerpoint file test ENDING at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
echo. >> %logfile%

echo Waiting for 1 minute to close the Powerpoint program
timeout /t 60 /NOBREAK >null
taskkill /F /IM wpp.exe /T

echo Waiting for 1 hour to restart...
timeout /t 10 /NOBREAK >null
goto loop
```

Comment: The only idea I have is to try to print the PowerPoint file to a dummy printer, using the command line switch that is also used by the context menu item *Print*, because this opens *and* closes PowerPoint; in that case you'd need to use `start "" /WAIT "\path\to\PowerPoint.exe /switch_to_print "PowerPoint_presentation.ppt"`...

Comment: If you want to measure network performance, measure the time copying the large .ppt file from the server to the local machine running Powerpoint. Rendering the graphics and other processing is dependent on the speed of the local computer, not the server or network.

Comment: Ordinarily I'd agree with @Liturgist but there might be some oddities in the case of PPT.  For example, it's going to create a temp file in the same folder as the original file you're opening.  It's not immediately apparent how often, how much and how quickly it will write to that temp file, but that will add overhead.  IOW, to measure how fast PPT opens a file over the network, the best bet is probably going to be to measure how fast PPT opens the file.  Is there some reason not to automate this from w/in PPT though?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - I agree with you. I did not know that Powerpoint would make a temp file in the original file directory. What if it is read-only? Regardless, does Powerpoint do anything that says, "I'm fully loaded and showing" after it starts?

Comment: Not sure what'll happen if the folder where the PPT/X lives is read-only.  Perhaps PPT will use TEMP.  I don't think PPT will do anything to let you know it's loaded, at least nothing that's accessible to a BAT file.  VBScript would probably be a better choice. My guess is that it'll block while the PPT is opening the file.  Get the start time, tell PPT to start and open the file, get the end time, subtract the times and you have your answer.  Or you could do it via VBA from within PPT or from Excel etc.